# i am getting an Runtime Error when I try to submit this program in an online judge but it works fine on a local console

Tags: python-3.x, runtime-error

This program traverses through a matrix diagonally.
For some reasons, it is running and showing correct results in my local console.

But when I try to submit it to an online judge, it shows a `Runtime Error`.

I referred to sources on stack overflow on what could be the possible causes for a Runtime error. But I am unable to pinpoint the error here.

```
matrix = []
l = []
n,m = map(int,input().split())
for i in range(n):
    r = list(map(int,input().split()))
    matrix.append(r)

i = j = 0
for k in range(m-1):
    j = k
    i = 0
    while j >= 0:
        l.append(matrix[i][j])
        i += 1
        j -= 1
for k in range(n):
    j = m - 1
    i = k
    while i <= n - 1:
        l.append(matrix[i][j])
        i += 1
        j -= 1
for i in l:
    print (i)
```

I thought it has something to do with handling the input() as other cases on this site have mentioned, but I have used a similar input method for some questions on the same Judge and it has worked fine.

Other than that, all the variables are defined properly.

Please suggest.

Comment: you need to specify what for runtime error you are getting. Generally if you code runs locally then this question is not related to python itself but to the platform. For example, the online platform might be using different version of python etc

Comment: Can you please explain what do you mean by "you need to specify what for runtime error you are getting"? 
I have submitted different programs on the online judge earlier (for different questions), and they all used python-3.7 and were accepted properly. I am not sure what is causing error in this one.